# Optimizing for global minimum

Tags: r, optimization, confidence-interval, sample-size

I am attempting to use `optimize()` to find the minimum value of n for the following function (Clopper-Pearson lower bound):

```
f <- function (n, p=0.5) 
 (1 + (n - p*n + 1) / 
    (p*n*qf(p= .025, df1= 2*p, df2= 2*(n - p + 1))))^-1
```

And here is how I attempted to optimize it:

```
n_clop <- optimize(f.1, c(300,400), maximum = FALSE, p=0.5)
n_clop
```

I did this over the interval [300,400] because I suspect the value to be between within it but ultimately I would like to do the optimization between 0 and infinity. It seems that this command is producing a local minimum because no matter the interval it produces the lower bound of that interval as the minimum - which is not what I suspect from [clopper-pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval). So, my two questions are how to properly find a global minimum in R and how to so over any interval?

Comment: Also - I would like the function to equal 0.5 (the half-width of the confidence interval for proportion) and calculate n for this. Not sure my set up is correct.

Comment: by the way, SO policy is that you don't need to include the name of the programming language (R) in the question title -- the [r] tag is supposed to be sufficient

Comment: There's no general way to do this for every function. What are you willing to assume to make this solvable? Global optimization is not an easy problem for any language to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've *very briefly* looked over the [Wikipedia page you linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) and don't see any obvious typos in your formula (although I feel like it should be 0.975=1-alpha/2 rather than 0.025=alpha/2?). However, evaluating the function you've coded over a very broad scale suggests that there are no local minima that are messing you up. My strong guess would be that either your logic is wrong (i.e., n->0 is really the right answer) or that you haven't coded what you think you're coding, due to a typo (possibly in the Wikipedia article, although that seems unlikely) or a thinko.

```
f <- function (n, p=0.5) 
 (1 + (n - p*n + 1) / 
    (p*n*qf(p= .025, df1= 2*p, df2= 2*(n - p + 1))))^-1
```

Confirm that you're getting the right answer for the interval you chose:

```
curve(f(x),c(300,400))
```

Evaluating over a broad range (n=0.00001 to 1000000):

```
curve(f(10^x),c(-5,7))
```

[image]

As @MrFlick suggests, global optimization is hard. You could start with `optim(...method="SANN")` but the best answer is definitely case-specific.